# Custom event binding in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events, jquery-ui-sortable

I've found some strange behavior in Meteor's event binding, which I'm not sure is a bug. First, just some background information. I have a bunch of lists of cards in columns (`funnelColumn` template), each of which containing a bunch of cards (`dealCard` template). I'm using [`Sortable`](https://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/) to allow drag-and-drop between lists. Now, I want to pass the responsibility for the update to the `dealCard` template, so I'm just using `$.trigger` to pass the data. More concretely, this is how it translates to code:

```
Template.funnelColumn.onRendered(function() {
  var columnName = template.data.model.name;
  Sortable.create(this.find('.deal-list'), {
    group: 'funnelColumns',
    onAdd: function(e) { $(e.item).trigger('onAdd', columnName); }
  });
});
```

### The actual problem

The thing is that, in those circumstances (using custom events), Meteor's `Template.prototype.events` doesn't seem to do the binding. The event bubbles normally, but the handlers are not always (but also not never) called.

```
Template.dealCard.onRendered(function() {
  this.$('.deal-card').on('onAdd', function(e, data) {
    // binding here is okay
  });
});

Template.dealCard.events({
  'onAdd .deal-card': function(e, item) {
    // this handler only gets called sometimes
  }
});
```

I tried to take a look at the [`Template.prototype.events`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/blaze/template.js#L468) code, but Meteor's code is too intricate for me.

Comment: As an alternative suggest to try passing custom events with something like https://github.com/raix/Meteor-EventEmitter/ or Signals.js .  I ran into that issue as well, don't have a detailed explanation of why it occurs, I think the listener is bound to the dom element instance which can get replaced during re-renders.  The only reliable way I found to pass around custom jquery events using trigger was to trigger and listen via 'body', which felt convoluted.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up using EventEmitter. I was just wondering whether that's a bug I should report or not!